# Python Linear Regression Line with Stock Data - Get the Closing Prices on the y-Axis

Tags: python, regression, line, stock

I used a previous thread here on stackoverflow in order to get to the point where I find myself. I want to make a stock chart that shows the line of best fit. I mostly have it working except for one problem. The y-Axis shows a normalized scale of -0.10 to 0.25 rather than the price of the stock. I want the price of the stock to be displayed on the y-Axis.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import numpy as np
import pandas_datareader.data as web
import pandas as pd
import datetime
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
import statistics as stat

#get adjusted close price of Tencent from yahoo
start = datetime.datetime(2020, 5, 21)
end = datetime.datetime(2021, 5, 21)
tencent = pd.DataFrame()
tencent = web.DataReader('IBM', 'yahoo', start, end)['Adj Close']

nomalized_return=np.log(tencent/tencent.iloc[0])

df = pd.DataFrame(data=nomalized_return)

df = df.resample('D').asfreq()

# Create a 'x' and 'y' column for convenience
df['y'] = df['Adj Close']     # create a new y-col (optional)
df['x'] = np.arange(len(df))  # create x-col of continuous integers


# Drop the rows that contain missing days
df = df.dropna()

X=df['x'].values[:, np.newaxis]
y=df['y'].values[:, np.newaxis]

# Fit linear regression model using scikit-learn
lin_reg = LinearRegression()
lin_reg.fit(X, y)

# Make predictions w.r.t. 'x' and store it in a column called 'y_pred'
df['y_pred'] = lin_reg.predict(df['x'].values[:, np.newaxis])

df['above']= y + np.std(y)
df['below']= y - np.std(y)
# Plot 'y' and 'y_pred' vs 'DateTimeIndex`
df[['y', 'y_pred']].plot()


plt.show()
```

The problem is with these lines

```
nomalized_return=np.log(tencent/tencent.iloc[0])

df = pd.DataFrame(data=nomalized_return)
```

If I replace `df = pd.DataFrame(data=nomalized_return)` with `df = pd.DataFrame(data=tencent)` then it works. I get the prices on the y-Axis but then the regression line ends up being wrong.
Anyway, the image below shows what I'm getting with the code above and it shows the problem.

[image: chart if IBM with a regression line]

Comment: a comment from a fitting standpoint: "best fit" ... ?! I believe you believe in Occam's razor too much :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can scale the response back back taking the exponential and multiplying by the first value:

```
df['y_pred'] = lin_reg.predict(df['x'].values[:, np.newaxis])
df['y_unscaled'] = tencent
df['y_pred_unscaled'] = np.exp(df['y_pred']) * tencent.iloc[0]

df[['y_unscaled', 'y_pred_unscaled']].plot()
```

[image]